# Button click event not happening

Tags: html, css, gwt

Ive got a bunch of menu button's I've recently styled with CSS

```
<button type="button" class="menu">Menu Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
button.menu {
    font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    color: #1a3e66;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 134px;
}

button.menu:hover {
    padding-right: 49px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.menu:active {
    padding-right: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

If you click where the padding changes no click event fires. Is there any way to move the text around within the button or fix this behavior?

EDIT: Updated and removed extraneous information.

Comment: It's not easy to help you without the images. But if you don't feel confortable with CSS, you can you use this site (http://css3button.net/) to make nice CSS3 button

Comment: I actually used css to make them but had to turn them into sprites because I needed the width to include the drop shadow. the problem persists without the background image.

Comment: @pith That's BS. Replacing the images with solid colors demonstrates the problem just as well. (That said, OP, that's what you should've done. Keep your code samples as simple as possible.)

Answer (score 1):

[:active selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) its not a  [click event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

active in css mean when you just click something happends whenever is the click still active. What you need is  [click event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

Comment: I've got one and its already working on 90% of the button, just not the section that moves. Which also happens to be where most people tend to click on these buttons                                      `Button b = new Button("Menu");                      b.setStyleName(STYLE_MENU);                                           b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {                                  @Override public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {                      stuff()                                                                         } });`